# Preventing Paperclip from deleting/overwriting attachments on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to prevent Paperclip from deleting the old version of an attachment (image).

I have a model, Site, which has an attachment, logo. I would like to keep the old logos around since I will be keeping track of changes to the model and would like to view the history of logos.

I'm keeping track of the changes in another model, which has a reference to file paths. My problem is that when updating a site with a new logo, Paperclip will flush the old logo first.

It surprises me that there's not an option you can switch to prevent Paperclip from flushing the old attachment before creating the new one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There's a new option that tells paperclip to preserve old attachments:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/commit/65e8d4f6de50732d8e1b
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/60

Simple to use:

```
has_attached_file => :attachment,
                     :styles => { :thumb => 100x100! },
                     :preserve_files => true
```

It's not documented yet and took some digging to find so I wanted to share it here.

Comment: Thank you. +1 from here, even though you didn't solve my problem at the time.

Comment: As of today, `preserve_files` seems deprecated, for the latest paperclip API: http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/ClassMethods:has_attached_file

See `keep_old_files`: Keep the existing attachment files (original + resized) from being automatically deleted when an attachment is cleared or updated. Defaults to false.

Comment: @AdrienSchuler I read those two as being separate. `preserve_files` will keep files even if the parent record is deleted, where as `keep_old_files` doesn't give this assurance.

Comment: Is anybody else noticing that Paperclip still sets all the attachment attributes to `nil` when destroying? This makes it hard to just clear the `deleted_at` attribute to restore the record because all the important attributes are set to `nil`.

Comment: is there any solution to avoid paperclip to set these attributes as NIL ? @JoshuaPinter

Comment: @Kashif Not that I found, I don't think.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter thanks. i want to delete and then undelete later. so, i kept a separate  DB field :(

Comment: @Kashif What is your "separate DB field"? Something like `deleted_at`?

Comment: @JoshuaPinter i marked a record as archived and will restore it later. i kept is_archived a boolean field

Comment: @Kashif Nice one. Hopefully we can get this properly fixed at some point, though.

Answer (score 1):

Because attachments are defined at the class level, Paperclip interpolates the symbols in your strings using it's own interpolation library. You can create your own interpolations using this library.

I would add a field to the model called `attachment_version` or something similar, and then increment this version number each time the file is changed. Then, create an interpolation for it in an initializer file:

```
Paperclip.interpolates :version do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.attachment_version
end
```

Now you can use `:version` in your strings:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :something, :path => " :rails_root/public/somethings/etc/:version.:extension"
end
```

See [the wiki documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/interpolations) for more information.

**[Update]**

After some digging around (see the comments to this answer), I've come to the conclusion that Paperclip will *still* delete the old attachment due to code that's called in `Paperclip::Atachment#attach`. Probably the best way to deal with this is to create a new storage engine based on [`Paperclip::Storage::Filesystem`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/storage/filesystem.rb) and overwrite `#flush_deletes`. Note that there is no way in that method to tell if a file is being queued for deletion because of the model it belongs to being deleted or a new file is being uploaded in its place.

Comment: It occurs to me that Paperclip may still delete the old file, just by default, even if the names do not match...

Comment: This appears to be the case. `Paperclip::Attachment#assign` calls `#clear`, which calls `queue_existing_for_delete`, which in turn does exactly what it sounds like it does. You *could* create a new storage engine based on https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/storage/filesystem.rb and modify `#flush_deletes` as necessary.

Comment: Thanks BinaryMuse, that seems to be the best way to go about it at the moment. You should create an answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

lib/paperclip_monkey_patch.rb:

```
module Paperclip
  class Attachment
   def clear
    # nop
    #raise "hell"
    # op
    instance_write(:file_name, nil)
    instance_write(:content_type, nil)
    instance_write(:file_size, nil)
    instance_write(:updated_at, nil)
  end
 end
end
```

Then add this line at the top of any file that deleted attachments:

require 'paperclip_monkey_patch'

Thanks to [Ruby Forum](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1912268)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Paperclip attachments at when working on a Rails blog last summer.

There is a patch that addresses this. I wasn't able to get it working for myself, but it's worth a shot!

http://github.com/alainravet/paperclip/tree/keep_old_files