# Revision Control - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have this application i'm working on and it works just fine. I am using paperclip for image upload. User's can upload logos after which an admin can accept them or ask them for changes after which they will upload an updated version after they make ammends.

Right now, when you edit with paperclip (upload a new image) it deletes the old one. I want like to keep a revision of how the logos have changed over time. The old images should be accessible in some kind of history. Are there any tutorials on how to do this, or how can I go about implementing this functionality?

Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this
http://eggsonbread.com/2009/07/23/file-versioning-in-ruby-on-rails-with-paperclip-acts_as_versioned/
[Preventing Paperclip from deleting/overwriting attachments on update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911191/preventing-paperclip-from-deleting-overwriting-attachments-on-update)

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved if you think of your revisions as associations.

You can have your Logo model and a Revision model :

```
class Logo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :revisions, inverse_of: :logo


class Revision < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :logo

  has_attached_file :image#, ...
```

Now if you want the current logo :

```
@logo.revisions.last.image
```

Edit : if you expect to add revisions to other things, consider naming Revision model something more explicit, like LogoRevision.

If you have few models and everything is about logo, Revision is enough.